# C++ , std::sort .Error:(218, 29) error: no viable overloaded '='

Tags: android, c++, sorting, opencv, c++11

sorry , maybe i am not declare clearly .

first, i have a vector of point

```
vector<Point> squares
```

it contains four point ,But do not know their respective positions

maybe not a positive rectangle .

so , i want to sort them based of their 'y'

and this code

```
 std::sort(squares.begin(), squares.end(), comp);

struct str{
bool operator() ( Point a, Point b ){
    if ( a.y != b.y )
        return a.y < b.y;
    return a.x <= b.x ;
}} comp;
```

but when i run the program, i got this error .

```
Android/android-ndk-r14b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/stl_heap.h
Error:(218, 29) error: no viable overloaded '='
```

Comment: What is `squares`? Please post MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You write the compiler found an error in line `218`. Which line is it? If this your code or a part of standard library?

Comment: the ‘squares’  : it is vetor <Point> .  (the point, it is a point  contains 'x' and 'y')

Comment: Why does your point_comparator use cv::Point2f? Maybe you need to use Point.

Comment: Is it really `std::vector<Point>` or a `std::vector<cv::Point2f>`? If the first option, the type conversion issues may raise. Please include all relevant code in the question text, help us help you.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33854595/5008845)

Comment: Your `operator()` doesn't meet the requirements of a strict weak ordering (e.g. it violates irreflexivity: `comp(a, a) == true`). Therefore, your program exhibits undefined behavior. Roughly speaking, the comparator should resemble `<`, whereas yours resembles `<=`.